# ui-bootstrap rating titles attribute - how to show it?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

The `uib-rating` has a `titles` attribute, where strings are defined for the rating icons. Is there a way these titles can be used as captions? I didn't find any documentation on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the `titles` in the scope like this:

```js
$scope.titles = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'];
```

and then reference this in the HTML:

```html
<uib-rating ... titles="titles"></uib-rating>
```

You can access the caption of the currently selected rating using:

```js
$scope.titles[Number(currentRating) - 1];
```

I've had to `$watch` the `rate` variable for changes so I can update the caption accordingly:

```js
$scope.$watch('rate', function(value) {
    $scope.caption = $scope.titles[Number(value) - 1];
});
```

I've created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dzdvpguDCmjyIYGV2GOC?p=preview) where upon selecting a new rating, the text below will show the corresponding caption.

**Edit: How to show caption upon hover:**

You can add the line to access the caption to the hover function:

```js
$scope.hoveringOver = function(value) {
  $scope.overStar = value;
  $scope.percent = 100 * (value / $scope.max);
  $scope.caption = $scope.titles[Number(value) - 1];
};
```

and define a `on-leave` function that resets the caption:

```js
$scope.hoveringOut = function() {    
  $scope.overStar = null;
  $scope.caption = null;
}
```

```html
<uib-rating ... on-leave="hoveringOut()"></uib-rating>
```

Please see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/B38pN494ppjkIsE5Gb9m?p=preview) for a demo.

Comment: Thankd a lot @ian. Very nice idea. I will, however, try to use the hovering functions to show the caption, I guess with that I won't need the `$watch`.

Comment: That's correct. I've updated my answer and there's a second Plunker to show how you can display the caption upon hovering. Original answer left in case anyone finds this from a search and wants to do it upon selection.